# jQuery UI select outer container and not inner container for drop target

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select only the outer container for the drop target with jQuery UI.

I am trying to drop in media-content but not in media-list-items.

The reason is that media-list-items is not the full width of it's parent and I only want to drop to the right side which is a different background color the full height.

HTML:

```
<div class="media-content clearfix ui-droppable on" style="">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="./">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="media-list-items clearfix"> 
                <ul data-gallery_id="18" class="media-list ui-sortable" style="">
                    <li id="media_17"></li>
                    <li id="media_15"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $trash = $('.media-content:not(.media-list-items), .media-content');
    $trash.droppable({ 
    accept: '.media-list > li',  
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('trashed');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KazeG/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can achieve what you want without adding another element as your "trash" droppable. With some neat css you can make it look pretty much the same :)

**html**

```
<div class="media-content">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="./">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="trash"></div> <!-- added a trash element -->
            <div class="media-list-items">    
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li id="media_25"></li>
                    <li id="media_26"></li>
                    <li id="media_27"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.media-content {
    position: relative; /* makes it contain absolutely positioned descendants */
}
.media-content .trash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; /* stretches to full height of .media-content */
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
}
```

**js**

```
$('.media-content .trash').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('trashed');
    }
});
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/KazeG/6/